# Функция isalpha. Можна ли сделать чтобы она работала с кириллицей

Tags: c++

Функция isalpha работает так - если символ = букве, то возвращается true, если что-то другое то false. Но она за буквы считает только латиницу. Можна ли сделать что-бы она работала с кириллицей?

Comment: Да, передайте вторым аргументом локализацию

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Передайте в функцию локаль:

```
std::locale loc("en_US.UTF8"); // unicode
// или
std::locale loc2("C"); // Cyrillic
std::isalpha('Ж', loc);
```